# Searching list C# by containing letters

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `List<string>` with some words. 
I want to get all of elements, witch contains letters in this schema:
`a00b0c000d` - `0` is random char, `a,b,c,d` - are constantly chars in string.

How can I do this? Can I do this only with Regex? There isn't any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, instead of a regex you can use LINQ to check for specific characters in the respective positions. But I'd definitely prefer a regular expression.

```
var result = yourList
    .Where(x => x[0] == "a")
    .Where(x => x[3] == "b")
    .Where(x => x[5] == "c")
    .Where(x => x[9] == "d")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do it with Regex and LINQ:

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"a..b.c...d"); 
//if you want whole string match use ^a..b.c...d$
var result = yourList.Where(yourRegex.IsMatch);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be start and end of line anchors `^` and `$` used in there, in case the list contains any (erroneous?) longer strings, too?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It said contains, so I assume he doesn't. However, I'll add that as an option.

Comment: Ah, true - depending on how the question is interpreted (and some of the answers interpreted it like this), one could read "contains, at specific positions" - in fact, your solution assumed specific relative positions of the characters as well, just not absolute with respect to the string boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IndexOfAny()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany.aspx) method for string after looping through List.`IndexOfAny` searches a string for many values.

```
 List<string> words = new List<string>();
 foreach(string word in words)
 {
    int match = word.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'});
    if(match!=-1)
    {
        //Processing Logic here
    }
  }
```

- It reports the index of the first occurrence in this instance of any character in a specified array of Unicode characters.
- The method returns -1 if the characters in the array are not found in this instance.

Comment: By definition, wouldn't IndexOfAny return just the first found index? Or it still does check for every character inside the given parameter?

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way would be to just iterate over the list.

```
List<string> matches = new List<string>();
myList.ForEach((x) => { if(x[0] == 'a' && x[3] == 'b' && x[5] == 'c' && x[9] == 'd') matches.Add(x);  });
```

Or you can use LINQ which might be slightly slower but unlikely to be a bottleneck.

```
var matches = myList.Where(x => x[0] == 'a' && x[3] == 'b' && x[5] == 'c' && x[9] == 'd').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using Regex, you could probably do something along the lines of

```
        List<string> stromgs = new List<string>();

        foreach (var s in stromgs)
        {
            var sa = s.Select(c => c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();

            if (sa.Contains("a") && sa.Contains("b") && sa.Contains("c") && sa.Contains("d"))
                yield return s;
        }
```

To get the results you are after. I haven't profiled this code so it could be a lot slower than using regular expressions for all I know, but it should give you a way to avoid Regex altogether (which is something I usually tend to do).